# Why is this average zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Let $\mathbf B(r, \theta, z)$ be the magnetic field in cylindrical coordinates. Define $\mathbf B(r=0) = B_0\mathbf k$. Now, the field goes slowly varying its value in first order:
$$
\mathbf B(r, \theta, z) = B_0\mathbf k + \left(\mathbf r\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf B
$$

Define the average $\left<\cdot\right>$ to be the average over circunference of specified fixed $r$ and $z$. Ie:
$$
\left< f(r, \theta, z)\right>_{r, z} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(r, \theta, z)d\theta
$$

Now, I was reading a book that said the following:
$$
\mbox{Since B is single-valued: }\left< \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial B_\theta}{\partial\theta}\right)\right> = 
\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial B_\theta}{\partial\theta}\right)d\theta = 0
$$

Notice the book's $B$ is not bold, ie, $\mathbf B$. I can only guess then $B = |\mathbf B|$. Also.. what is single-valued? What does he means by that? Anyway...

Well.. I fail to see how can this average be zero. On the contrary, I think it should be non-zero. I have plenty of arguments to show it should be non-zero (all of them mathematical). It only leaves the physics of $B$-fields to impose some restriction such that this is true. But I fail to see anything helping either in this case.

Any help?

Comment: A single-valued function is a  function that, for each point in the domain, has a unique value in the range. It is therefore one-to-one or many-to-one.

Comment: @CountTo10 Then every function is by definition single-valued. And fields are functions. And B-Fields are fields. So.. Why would he say something so obvious? I don't think he is considering the mathematical "single-valued". I don't know what he means... =(.

Comment: Don't worry, it is obvious. We like to say things like this to emphasize that $B$ must be the same at $\theta=0$ and at $\theta=2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is very simple. Let's consider

$$\oint \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\ d\theta$$

over a circle of fixed $r$ with $f$ some continuous function of $r$ and $\theta$. We can take this integral to begin at $\theta=0$ and go all the way around and end at $\theta=2\pi$, which of course is the same point. Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\oint \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\ d\theta = f\big|^{2\pi}_0
= f(2\pi)-f(0)=0$$

since after all $\theta=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$ are the same point.